# Context menu JavaScript can not get the selected text if the text is a input tag / textbox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox-addon, contextmenu, clipboard

I had a very big problem, to get somehow the selected text from the webpage then process it using a contextmenu... when I solved for `Chrome`, `Firefox`, and `IE11`, I found I can't get the selected text in `Firefox` and `Internet Explorer` when the selected text is in a Input box....

I have searched for days to solve somehow, and finally I had success...

This was the original script for `Internet Explorer`

```js
var parentwin = external.menuArguments
var selectedText = getSel();


function getSel(){
  var w=window,d=parentwin.document,gS='getSelection';
  return (''+(w[gS]?w[gS]():d[gS]?d[gS]():d.selection.createRange().text)).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
}
```

And this for `FireFox`

```js
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");
var {Cc,Ci} = require('chrome');
var simpleGetLibrary = null;
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Get selected text",
  context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                 '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                 '});',
  onMessage: function (selectionText) {
    console.log(selectionText);
 clipboard.set(selectionText);   //this line copy the selected text to Clipboard
}
```

But I had no idea, how I can solve to get somehow the text when it is in a input box...  `<INPUT> ...</INPUT>`
The solution is the following...

Answer (score 1):

For `Internet Explorer` `IE11`

```js
var parentwin = external.menuArguments
var selectedText = getSel();


function getSel(){
  var w=parentwin.window,d=parentwin.document,gS='getSelection';
  var selectedText;
  var rv=(''+(w[gS]?w[gS]():d[gS]?d[gS]():d.selection.createRange().text)).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
  parentwin.console.log("the selected text is in first try is:"+rv);
  
 if (rv=="") {
   var allinput = parentwin.document.getElementsByTagName("input");  //I get an array of all input tags
   var index;
   var newsel;
   var found="false";
   for (index = 0; index < allinput.length; index++) {
    parentwin.console.log("index: "+index);
    newsel="";
    parentwin.console.log("newsel= ");
    try {
      var ss = allinput[index].selectionStart;
      parentwin.console.log("ss");
      var se = allinput[index].selectionEnd;
      parentwin.console.log("se");
      if (typeof ss === "number" && typeof se === "number") {
        newsel=allinput[index].value.substring(ss, se);
        found=newsel;
        if (newsel.length>0){
        rv=newsel;
        found="true";
        allinput[index].selectionEnd=allinput[index].selectionStart;
        newsel="";
        }
      }
    }
    catch(err){}
    parentwin.console.log("input fields "+index+"/"+allinput.length+" fieldname:"+allinput[index].getAttribute("name")+" selection: "+newsel);
    if (found=="true"){
    index=allinput.length;
    }
   }
   parentwin.console.log("found=:"+found);
 }
  return rv;
}
```

And for `Firefox` is a little bit tricky, because I can't have access to the DOM so I need to resolve this in ContentScript building and then I send directly the result.. because I can't solve how to get only the selection, I send the value of the input box, is don't matter if is not all selected...

```js
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");
var preferences = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs;
var {Cc,Ci} = require('chrome');
var simpleGetLibrary = null;
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Get selected text",
  context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
     '  console.log("Selected node is: "+node.nodeName);' +
     '  console.log("Selected value is: "+node.value);' +
                 '  if (text.lenght>0)' +
     '  self.postMessage(text);' +
     '  else ' +
     '  if (node.nodeName=="INPUT")' +
     '  self.postMessage(node.value);' +
     '});',
  onMessage: function (selectionText) {
    console.log("Selection sent for processing is: "+selectionText);
    clipboard.set(selectionText);   //this line copy the selected text to Clipboard
  }
```

Comment: What an awesome solution! Nicely typed out! Always props to people who figure out their question and come back and share the answer!